# Build LINQ queries dynamically - force using sp_executesql instead of raw query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I need to build queries dynamically (entity classes have over 30 properties and I want to avoid multiple if statements).
I solved this using reflection and expression tree (iterate by properies and append predicate if some search criteria is specified).
The problem is that it generates raw SQL script.

Example

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
    [Extent1].[ManufacturerId] AS [ManufacturerId], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 3 = [Extent1].[ManufacturerId]
```

I need to obtain query using **sp_executesql** procedure (resuing the same query execution plan).

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
    [Extent1].[ManufacturerId] AS [ManufacturerId], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ManufacturerId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=3
```

It turned out the problem is in the method below. It uses Expression.Constant to create Expression object. I don't know what should I replace it with.

```
public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEqual<TItem, TValue>(
    this PropertyInfo property, TValue value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, property),
        Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue)));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: The expression should be equivalent. Perhaps it is how you use it... What `.Where` overload are you using?

Comment: Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to let EF use a parameter instead of constant value, you need to introduce a closure (similar to what C# compiler does for compile time expressions).

One way is to create anonymous type and bind it's property:

```
var closure = new { value };
var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, property),
    Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(closure), "value"));
```

Another way is to actually use the C# compiler to create a closure expression and bind it's body:

```
Expression<Func<TValue>> closure = () => value;
var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, property),
    closure.Body);
```